# Why does these nested forEach loops behave like this?

Tags: javascript, loops, dictionary, foreach, nested-loops

I'm trying to build a Javascript generator based on maps, but I'm facing a big issue.
To summarize, **here's a scheme of the expected behaviour** :

- A js map named `finalSelection` is created based on user's inputs when one or more items are being selected (html basic select). This map is composed of ingredients (key), and for each ingredient, another map containing its effects (value).

  - It goes like this (e.g.) : `finalSelection = {"Black Pepper": {"Fortify Constitution": 3, "Fortify Constitution": 3, "Resist Fire": 2, "Weakness to Fire": 1, "Resist Acid": 1}, ...};`
- When this user clicks on a `generateButton` HTML button, a field named `result` should display a the result of the generation based on the previously described map, something like this : `"You generated a potion ! 'Weakness to necrotics' : 6/10"`

There's a very simple logic behind the generator :

- If among all the ingredients (html select options) that the user selected and that are packed into the `finalSelection` map, the generator can find two (or more) occurences of an effect inside these ingredients, it displays the name of the effect and the sum of the two values : `You created a potion ! ${effectName} : ${effectValue1 + effectValue2}`.
- The ingredients need to be two (or more) different ones.

**To achieve this, I've build a generator based on nested 'forEach' loops and some basic 'if...else' statements :**

```
// Core algorythm of the generation process
function generatePotion() {
    finalSelection.forEach(function(ingredientEffects, ingredientName, finalSelection) {
        Object.entries(ingredientEffects).forEach(function(effectValue, effectName, ingredientEffects) {
            finalSelection.forEach(function(ingredientEffects2, ingredientName2, finalSelection) {
                Object.entries(ingredientEffects2).forEach(function(effectValue2, effectName2, ingredientEffects2) {
                    if (ingredientName !== ingredientName2) {
                        if (effectName === effectName2) {
                            potion = `${effectName} : ${effectValue + effectValue2}`;
                        }
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    })
    return potion;
}
```

**And a very simple 'click' listener :**

```
// Listen to the state of the 'Generate' button
var generateButton = $('#generateButton');
generateButton.on('click', function() {
    if (finalSelection.size !== 0) {
    generatePotion();
    potion = generatePotion();
    result.innerHTML = potion;
    } else {
        result.innerHTML = "Nothing Selected.";
    }
    console.log(potion);
});
```

But I'm not getting the expected behaviour, instead of something like `Weakness to Necrotics : 6/10` I get this : `4 : Fortify Investigation,1Weakness to Fire,2`.

***Here's a JSFiddle :***

https://jsfiddle.net/d378szxw/

So, after hours and hours of headache, I would like to ask some help to the community !
Thanks a lot in advance for your precious help, and please excuse the possible mispellings of a french guy !

Comment: Can you add some details for an [mcve]? We'd probably need a sample input (just an object) that we can use to reproduces this behaviour.

Comment: Of course, I'll edit this post in a second.

Comment: There's now a complete JSFiddle at the end of the post.

Comment: forEach callback arguments are: (element, indexOfElement, wholeArray). That means `effectName` will always be a number, the index of `effectValue` in the array you are looping through. Your string `${effectName} : ${effectValue + effectValue2}` will evaluate to `indexOfFoundEffect: foundEffect1foundEffect2` in pseudo language terms.

Comment: Also, Object.entries returns an array of arrays that looks like `[[key1, value1], [key2, value2]]` and that's why when you put `effectValue` in a string it looks like `Fortify Investigation,1`.

Comment: Ok I understand the problem, thanks for your help. So is there a way to get the string value of the Index instead of its integer index value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
function generatePotion() {
  const effectObject = {};
  const resultPotion = '';
  finalSelection.forEach(function(ingredientEffects, ingredientName) {
    Object.keys(ingredientEffects).forEach(effect => {
      if (!effectObject[effect]) {
        effectObject[effect] = {
          value: ingredientEffects[effect],
          occurrences: 1
        };
      } else {
        effectObject[effect].occurrences++;
        effectObject[effect].values += ingredientEffects[effect];
      }
    });
  });
  Object.keys(effectObject).forEach(effect => {
    if (effectObject[effect].occurrences > 1) {
      resultPotion += `${effect} : ${effectObject[effect].value}`
    }
  }
  return resultPotion;
}
```

That will go over the finalSelection and create an object of Effects with number of occurrences and total value. What you want to do with this in the end is up to you, what I did is concatenate all effects that are found more than once and their value in a single string.

Comment: That is smart ! Thank you very much for your help ! Then I'll try to pimp it a bit to fit my need.

Comment: The generator is now online on Github Pages, thanks again for your precious help ! https://ajacquierbret.github.io/alchemy-potion-generator/